# When launching a ship meant to colonize a planet beyond our solar system, what would be the best location for the launch?

Tags: launch, rockets, colonization, interstellar-travel

If we were going to launch a ship meant to take a one way trip and colonize another planet outside of our solar system, what location on earth would serve as the best launch point? Could we use one that already exists or would we have to build a new one? I'm talking about a ship like in the one in the movie 'Pandorum' or the video game 'Civilization, Beyond Earth', with people, technology, food, plants etc. on it.

Comment: I think that any answers to this question would be too speculative.  We are significantly far away from being able to send colony ships to other star systems, so the best someone could do to answer your question would be to tell you good locations for launching really big ships.

Comment: Planets beyond our solar system will be orbiting other stars - many light years away. No matter what sort of propulsion system we might imagine, the trip will take a very long time. To endure such a long flight we'd have to imagine a very large ship - too large to launch from Earth's surface. So the answer would be: not on Earth at all. It would have to be assembled in orbit, take on its crew, passengers, supplies, etc. and depart from orbit. Even for mission concepts to Mars, a single launch seems unlikely, but rather multiple launches for on-orbit assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on this. As people look at the economics of space, big things in space only start to make sense when the materials to build them are in space. That would mean the refineries and factories are also in space, and the people who work there. This is orbital space, not on the surface of any large planet or moon. So we are talking about orbital settlements harvesting asteroids. Looking at orbital space the most likely spot for asteroid exploitation would be lagrange points. Possibly Earth / Moon lagrange points or the trojan asteroids, the Jupiter lagrange points. If we are already building huge spinning colonies in space, building a multi generational craft to travel to another star is not as big a leap.